# How I Can Say To Program To Know Should Put Which Operator For Calculate?

Tags: python

I am looking in Python to make one function to calculate numbers from 1 to 9 and find every list of it that *results* to 100 (explanation below).

I mean from 1 to 9 we have `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`  and we want our function to find answer 100 like: `1 + 2 + 34 - 5 + 67 - 8 + 9 = 100`.

Our function needs to find which kind of operator `+` or `-` when come between numbers between 1 to 9 to find answer which is 100.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: But why is it tagged `C` ?

Comment: He is completely beginner so he do not know much about stackoverflow

Comment: I always favor [backtracking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-algorithms/) for this kind of problems.  Basically you need to try 3 options (nothing, +, or -) between every two consecutive list items.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```py
from itertools import product
from typing import List


def function(numbers: List[int], target: int) -> None:
    def check():
        for number in numbers[1:]:
            if number < 0:
                return False
        return True

    assert check()

    for combination in product(['+', '-', ''], repeat=len(numbers) - 1):
        sum_string = ''
        for number, sign in zip(numbers, combination):
            sum_string += str(number) + str(sign)
        sum_string += str(numbers[-1])
        if eval(sum_string) == target:
            print(sum_string.replace('+', ' + ').replace('-', ' - '))


function([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 100)
```

Time complexity: O(3^len(numbers))

Comment: Thank You Very Much God Blessed You And Your Love.